# jquery html to object in each array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, object, each

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var a = $('#result').html();
                //var a = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
        $.each($.parseHTML(a), function(b){
            alert(b);
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="result">['a','b','c','d','e']</div>
</body>
```

How to transfer html to string? In fact `div#result` in an ajax callback data, I am tring to read `div#result` then use `$each` to parse this array, but this code only return first value then stopped. How to do in a right way? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Make sure you got the right JSON data in the JSON form `"`

```
<body>
<div id="result">['a','b','c','d','e']</div>
</body>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $('#result').html();
     a=a.replace(/'/g, '"');
    alert(a);

    $.each(JSON.parse(a), function(b){
        alert(b);
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mRkE4/4/)**

> Note: If you are using IE<=7 or the browser which has no support for
>   JSON, please include this js file in your page
>   https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Parse'

Comment: @fishman, for JSON data needs to be enclosed with `"` double quote. check the fiddle

Comment: Should be small P, not capital.

Comment: @Murali still throwing the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' `

Comment: @ArunPJohny, in fiddle? the data is not in a json format. For JSON it needs to be enclosed with double quote

Comment: @Murali I think that was the question? how to process the said string

Comment: @ArunPJohny, i am not sure how can we handle this single quote? Is it really a good solution to have single quotes replaced with double quote using .replace()?

Comment: @Murali, thanks, but if the data is not "json"? they are huge and from mysql, it is difficult transfer them into json data.

Comment: @fishman, but are you sure you always get this kind [`a`,`b`,...] only? i meant single quote data

Comment: @fishman if it is a trusted data you can think about using `eval()` it is evil but if you can trust the data then think about using it

Comment: @fishman but be aware about the security risks associated with it

Comment: @ArunPJohny, sometimes `eval` is called as `evil` :) so initially avoided that one. it is ok if the data is trusted and comes from our own domain